# Manipulating strings in LDAP

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have a contacts search form that uses LDAP. There's a name and surname. There's users that have non-standard letters in their names / surnames. For example:

```
Małgorzata Kozłowska
Jan Wąsowski
```

The request is not to distinguish big / small letters and ignore non-standard letters when searching for users so these queries would find the users:

```
malgorzata kozlowska
jan waSOWSKI
```

Is there any way to achieve this in LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

The issue of "special" characters can be usually be handled by proper escaping of the values as described in [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514)

As for case sensitivity for Distinguished Names, [it depends](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Distinguished%20Name%20Case%20Sensitivity).